# How to identify "Space is low" cause

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, pharo

So sometimes you get "Space is low" dialog in Pharo. Is it possible to somehow identify what is taking that much space?

Comment: Is this a general question, or this happens to you under special circumstances? Also, do you have any suspicion on what kind of objects could be taking too much memory?

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia yes, it is general. Because I know which package I have pre-loaded before this started to happen, so the developer of a package also should have enough knowledge to identify an issue. But I started to think: ok, someone not so advanced gets this error, what should he/she do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an easy problem because in the process of gathering that information you are likely to exceed the maximum amount of space.

There's `SmalltalkImage>>lowSpaceThreshold` that you could modify to get a bit more room for experimenting.

What you also can do is look at `SmalltalkImage>>memoryHogs`. That class variable will be populated by the VM (I think) with the top memory consuming objects (if such an object can be identified).

Another thing you can do if you're unable to pinpoint single instances of large objects, is to look at the number of all instances of all the classes. This takes a bit of space and you should be careful. But here's some code that would work (restricted to interesting packages):

```
classes := Class allSubclasses select: [ :class | class name beginsWith: 'AB' ].
(classes collect: [ :class | class -> class allInstances size ]) inspect.
```

Then, there's also `TBehavior>>instancesSizeInMemory` and `Object>>sizeInMemory`. These can really crash your image if you run them on a graph (you'll have to implement that yourself) but they give you a good indication about which objects consume how much memory.

You could adapt the code from above to the following to get the size of the instances:

```
classes := Class allSubclasses select: [ :class | class name beginsWith: 'AB' ].
(classes collect: [ :class | class -> class instancesSizeInMemory ]) inspect.
```

**Note:** code examples are meant for Pharo4.

Comment: I would point out that one could avoid creating intermediate collections (that take even more memory) by expressing the iterations with `SystemNavigation new allObjectsDo: aBlock` where `aBlock` is carefully written not to take much memory.

Comment: That's true. However, you will visit *every* object instead of only those that are interesting to you, which means instances of `Process`, `Context`, `BlockClosure`, `SmallInteger` etc. that are usually uninteresting but of which there are vast amounts.

Comment: Sure, the block argument should filter out non interesting objects based on the classes under suspicion, etc.